# how I can display information on the Cgridview according to the logged user in yii?

Tags: yii, rbac

I have this:
State:
id
data1

Company:
id
data1
state_fk

Planning
id
data1
company_fk

users roles in the system will be the name of a state,what I want is, according to the user roles, when he accesses to GridView Planning index i need that he only see whose having Companies whose states match with the user role. sorry for my English and thanks

Comment: I edited your question, cgridview is not part of yii2 but part of yii1. If you are actually talking about yii2 then edit it again and put the correct class in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add this in cgrid,

```
array (
'header' => 'Companies',
'value' => '$data->searchcompanies',
'type' => 'html', ),
```

and add this function in planning model,

```
public function getsearchcompanies(){
$companies  = Companies::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('state_id'=>$stateid));
foreach($companies as $company){
    $companynames[]=$company->company_name;
}
$regionname=implode('<br/>',$regionnames) ; 
return $regionname;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'visible' in CGridView widget :

```
array(
        'name' => 'company',
        'value' => '$data->searchcompanies',
        'visible' => Yii::app()->user->isAdmin,
    ),
```